# In Google App Engine, how do you keep your development datastore available after updating the SDK?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to keep a copy of your datastore file after updating the SDK, as you might know, updating the SDK will make old datastore incompatible with the new SDK and you can't access the data.

Is there an easy way to avoid this issue or should I save all the data to a text file or something and then repopulate the data automatically?

I am using GWT with Objectify by the way.

Comment: Because your development datastore will be running against code you are running for the first time to test it, you should never use it as the only copy of important data anyway. Your code might have a bug that accidentally deletes data.

Comment: The data is not important, I am just sick of manually repopulating the sample data every time I update the SDK.

Comment: FWIW, the python version of dev_appserver does not suffer from this problem because it is backed by SQLLite instead of a file.

Comment: I think that your idea (of using your app) to repopulate your local datastore automagically after a GAE/J SDK update is a sound one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to download and later upload your data when required as described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata?csw=1). Note that is mentions that "downloaded data might not include recently saved entities." if you are using a High replication datastore.